# How file transfer bidirectional in angularjs with support in safari

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http

**How file transfer bidirectional in angularjs with support in safari**

When is execute the required is correctly the result in navigator chrome, firefox, IE but not in safari by initialize the petition with blob

Code client

```
$http.get('/api/files/getFile')
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $log.debug('DATA RETURN:', data);
    var file = new Blob([ data ], {
        type : 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
    });
   //trick to download store a file having its URL
    var fileURL = (window.URL || window.webkitURL || {}).createObjectURL(file);
    var a         = document.createElement('a');
    a.href        = fileURL; 
    a.target      = '_blank';
    a.download    = 'yourfilename.docx';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $log.debug('DATA RETURN:', data);
});
```

Code server

```
exports.getFile = function(req, res) {
   var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'document.docx');
   var file = fileSystem.readFileSync(filePath, 'binary');
   res.setHeader('Content-Length', file.length);
   res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + 'newdocumetn.docx');
   res.contentType('application/vnd.openxmlformats-  officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
   res.download(filePath,'file_rename.docx', function(err){
   if (err) {
      log.info('Get file from server');
   } else {
     log.info('Get file from server');
   }
 });
};
```

Result in web [image: Result of execution in the safari in others navigator is correct]